# NumPy - Can this be vectorized?

Tags: python, numpy

Working on a new script and for the first time I'm diving into NumPy. The memory advantages are inheriently obvious, but vectorizing is a troublesome concept.

I have 2 NumPy arrays representing XY points and boxes, and for each point I need to determine which boxes the point is  found to intersect.

The two arrays have structures like so:

```
>>> points
array([[40.00183, 20.005],
       [39.9975, 20.0125],
       [57.01822, 16.997]], dtype=float32)

>>> boxes
array([[40.00183, 20.005, 39.9975, 20.0125],
       [39.9975, 20.0125, 57.01822, 16.997],
       [57.01822, 16.997, 40.00183, 20.005]], dtype=float32)
```

The actual values here are made up, in fact the boxes arent even boxes, but thats the structure. `points` is an N-D array with a shape of `(N, 2)` and `boxes` witha shape of `(M, 4)`.

The alogorithm for intersection testing is:

```
def intersect(p: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> bool:
    '''Intersection testing using DeMorgan's Law'''
    return ( p[0] < b[2] and
             p[0] > b[0] and
             p[1] < b[3] and
             p[1] > b[1] )
```

All the vectorizing I've seen involves scalars, I haven't seen any involving a function using 2 arrays.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206877/discussion-on-question-by-pstatix-numpy-can-this-be-vectorized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed! As it happens, I had exactly the same problem and coded the solution as follows:

```
def point_is_inside_box(point, bb):
  '''
  point: (x,y) np array of shape Nx2
  bb: (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax) np array of shape Mx4

  Return: boolean matrix MxN where each column stands for "point n is in box m"
  '''
  # Logic: xmin <= x < xmax and ymin <= y < ymax
  point = point[None,...]
  bb = bb[...,None,:]
  return (bb[...,0] < point[...,0]) & (point[...,0] < bb[...,2]) & (bb[...,1] < point[...,1]) & (point[...,1] < bb[...,3])
```

Essentially, the idea is to exploit numpy's broadcasting rules. Since the input is two vectors, I add dimensions s.t. `point` has shape `[1,N,2]` and `bb` has shape `[M,1,4]`. This way, the broadcasting will apply the `<` operators to every pair `(pt, box)` in the arrays, producing the result as a matrix of shape `[M,N]`.

**About the slicing:**

- `...` is called [*ellipsis*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and it's equivalent to as many `:` as necessary to fill the missing dimensions. You can think of it as a shortcut for "take everything from all the other dimensions I do't explicitly state here". So, for example, if `point` has shape `[42,2]`, I can select all `x` values via `point[:,0]` or `point[...,0]`. If, however, `point` has shape `[42,1,2]`, the second statement will *still* select all the x values, while the first statement won't work (it needs to change to `point[:,:,0]`)
- `None` is just equivalent to `np.newaxis`. I'm basically telling numpy to insert a new dimension in that specific position. One might argu tha using `np.newaxis` instead of `None` is more readable. And they'd be right.

**About memory consumption:**

Assuming no copies happen when adding extra dimensions to array (not sure if that's the case but I'd guess it does't happen), you'll need additional memory for `N*M` booleans, which might become a lot if you have a lot of points and boxes. Should that be the case, given the likely strong sparsity of the output matrix, it may be interesting to try using [`scipy`'s sparse matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) keeping the code structure the same. No clue if that would work, or whether it's performant, though.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your slicing, I've not seen `None` and `...` used before.

Comment: Let me add that in then

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks! Two things: 1.) To make `point` into `[N, 2, 1]`, wouldn't it be `point[..., None]`? 2.) Would you call this inside a loop for each point? Like `for point in points: point_is_inside_box(point, boxes)`? I wouldn't think you would.

Comment: 1) Indeed, I had a typo there, fixed :) 2) No, you call this on the vectors directly ("point" and "bb" ar a bit of a name abuse there, as they're actually the whole arrays)

Comment: 1.) Typo is still there right? `point = point[None, ...]` still showing for me. 2.) Thanks!

Comment: No, the typo was in the explanation. The code is the way it should be (`point` has shape `[1,N,2]`, boxes has shape `[M,1,4]`, result has shape `[M,N]`)

Comment: Alright, so I am fine with the syntax, but I don't understand the need for the additional axis.

Comment: It is necessary because of [numpy's broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules). You need it to tell numpy to apply the operator to all possible combinations of point and box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206864/discussion-between-pstatix-and-gphilo).

Comment: To your point about memory, I need to find a way to support large `(M, N)` grids. I receive a `MemoryError` for `np.bool` for an array of shape `(1.5m, 37m)`.

Comment: FYI, I ran the test in chucks of `(1.5m, 370)`; one run takes 6.8s, and I would require 100k runs thus resulting in 680000s of run time. Thats roughly 188h, so not really feasible/usable for bulk processing. However, it can be placed inside my current implementation (which uses a spatial index [thus reducing checks significantly]), and improve internal performance! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
def intersect2D(p: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    '''Intersection testing using DeMorgan's Law'''
    return np.logical_and(
         np.logical_and(p[:, 0] < b[:, 2], p[:, 0] > b[:, 0]),
         np.logical_and(p[:, 1] < b[:, 3], p[:, 1] > b[:, 1])
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

points = np.array(
    [[10, 12],
    [22, 24],
    [5, 10]]
)

boxes = np.array(
    [[0, 0, 100, 100],
    [15, 20, 50, 30],
    [4, 9, 6, 11]]
)

result = (points[:,:1] > boxes[:,0]) * \
         (points[:,:1] < boxes[:,2]) * \
         (points[:,1:] > boxes[:,1]) * \
         (points[:,1:] < boxes[:,3])
```

result is :

```
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]])
```

result[p][b] is True if point p is inside box b